# Do I need a transit visa in Paris and Panama?

Tags: visas, transit, filipino-citizens, panama, cdg

Visiting Costa Rica soon.

Depart from Hong Kong - Paris - Panama - Costa Rica (SJO).
I hold a Philippine Passport, do i still need transit visas for Paris and Panama?

Comment: What is your country of residence?

Answer (score 1):

- **Transit in Paris, France:** considering you are not going to another Schengen state after Paris, and that you have an onward ticket, you can TWOV (transit without visa) in Paris (for a maximum of 24 hours in transit).
- **Transit in Costa Rica:** TWOV is possible given that you have an onward ticket (for a maximum of 12 hours in transit).

[Source: TimaticWeb](http://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&HEALTH=1&VISA=1&&NA=PH&AR=HK&EM=HK&DE=CR&TR=FR&TR=PA&VT=FR&VT=HK&VT=PA&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=MS&subuser=MS)

Comment: The OP wants to transit through Panama, not Costa Rica.