# Do I need transit visa through Amsterdam going Costa Rica?

Tags: schengen, transit, transit-visas, filipino-citizens, panama

I hold a Philippine passport, planning to go Costa Rica for 5 days or so, I’ll fly with KLM ,do I need a transit visa in Amsterdam and Panama for lay over ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need a transit visa in Paris and Panama?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20673/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-in-paris-and-panama)

Answer (score 2):

Usually (**but not always**), you don't need transit visa if you aren't planning to enter the country in which you're transiting through (provided the airport you are flying through allows you to stay 'airside', which isn't the case, for example, in any US airports).

As a Philippine citizen, you don't need a visa to transit at Amsterdam airport.

Some nationalities require transit visas even for airside transit, without entering the country. For example, as a Philippine citizen you would need one to transit through a French airport, as Chris H mentioned in the comments.

You would also need a visa if you have two transits in the Schengen zone for example Manila-> Amsterdam-> Paris-> Costa Rica. As you'd be entering the Schengen zone proper, this would also apply for people with citizenship that doesn't need a visa for a single transit, as for those who needs a transit visa anyway they have to apply for it in case they are going to transit in the schengen zone and it depends on the nationality and the schengen state that you will be transiting through. Check this [link](https://consular.mfaservices.nl/schengen-visa/schengen-advisor/LHHVTQ/Advisor/Advisor/IntendedStay) to see if you are your nationality requires a transit visa for the Netherlands.

Comment: Though it's the right answer in this case, this is is a major oversimplification. Depending on citizenship (and even on which country within the Schengen zone the transit occurs), [some travellers need visas for all transit within the Schengen zone](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/apply_for_a_visa_en). For example: OP, as a citizen of the Philippines, can transit (remaining airside) visa-free in Amsterdam, but [wouldn't be able to do so in France](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/annex_7b_atv-national_lists_en.pdf).

Comment: @ChrisH Yes you are right that's I started my answer with usually and I added some of the exception that I know of

Comment: yes, but the exceptions you mentioned (US and making multiple Schengen stopovers, thus having to enter the Schengen zone) are respectively irrelevant and barely an exception anyway. Your answer sounds like a very blunt statement that nobody needs a visa to transit airside in Schengen unless they're making multiple stops, and could easily (for example) mislead OP into thinking they can change their flights to transit at CDG instead and still go visa-free. The correct response would be to edit your answer to make the *relevant* exceptions clear.

Comment: I edited my answer I hope it's more efficient now

Comment: The site you've linked to is an unofficial site that has a history of showing incorrect or outdated information.  Why link to an unofficial site when you can link to the official one?

Comment: @phoog Sorry I thought that's an official site, I have changed the link the dutch visa advisor

Comment: @phoog yeah haha but I thank everyone for the feedbacks

Answer (score 0):

[thabetmw's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/144186/16765) already answers the Schengen/Amsterdam part, so for the Panama branch of your layover, [according to this source (Spanish)](http://www.inmigrantesenpanama.com/2017/10/12/visa-para-entrar-a-panama-para-pasajeros-en-transito/) you do not require a visa as long as you do not have to go through Immigration and have a flight on the same airline. This applies to any nationality.